# Problem involving second degree polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polynomials

Let $ f : \bf R \to \bf R$ be a polynomial of the form $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$,$a_2 \neq 0$.If $E_1= \int_ {-1} ^{1} f(x)dx -[f(-1]+f(1)]$,$E_2=\int_ {-1} ^{1} f(x)dx -\frac {1}{2} [f(-1]+2f(0)+f(1)]$ Then show that $\vert E_1 \vert =4\vert E_2 \vert$.

Do we need to compute the value of $E_1$ and $E_2$ explicitly or is there any other quick way to see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E_1$ and $E_2$ are linear functionals on the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$. So it is enough to prove that $\vert E_1 \vert =4\vert E_2 \vert$ for $f=1,x,x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the well-known formula:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d \mkern 1mu x=\frac{b-a}6\Bigl(f(a)+4f\Bigl(\frac{a+b}2\Bigr)+f(b)\Bigr),$$
which is actually valid for polynomials of degree at most $3$.

Comment: Does it really?

Comment: Check it! The equality  is even true without the absolute value, if I'm not mistaken. Now, the formula I mention has to be proved – which is done as you say.